# Sending a voltage to RS232

Tags: c#, serial-port

I know that we can use pin no.3 to send the data as a output in RS232. But I am just wondering that there is another way to send only the voltage 5v to the RS232 in a short period? I just want that 5v to trigger a PIC Microcontroller to do something.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30swa673.aspx ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the DTREnable (Data Terminal Ready) property of the SerialPort class to apply a positive voltage to those respective pins. This could be used to signal an MCU.

Something along the lines of...

```
serialPort.DtrEnable = true; //High
currentThread.Sleep(1000);
serialPort.DtrEnable = false; //Low
currentThread.Sleep(1000);
```

However! the **voltage is likely to be incompatible** as RS232 operates -25 to 25 volts for 1/0's. You will likely need an inline driver/receiver such as a MAX232 chip to operate between the MCU and computer, or dependant on your skill level you could build a receiver circuit.

Comment: The differences in voltages is such a pain.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The code that you gave above is for changing high signal to low signal? and the next question is.. is it possible to make MCU work only when it detect the positive signal?

Comment: Yes there is, what you are talking about is called detecting a rising edge, or detecting the transition from low to high on a pin. There are lots of ways to do this; if your PIC has external interrupts then this is the ideal way, however if not then there are ways to poll the pin and detect the change from low to high. Either way there are plenty of examples out there no matter if your using c or asm!

Answer (score 2):

you can use RTS or DTR as long as you aren't using them on the PIC side for flow control

Comment: I don't think you can set the CTS pin from C#, but RTS and DTR are both good choices.

Comment: Watch out, could be more than 5 volts.  And it will be negative 5 volts when you invert the property.  You should use a diode to protect the PIC.

Answer (score 0):

PIC Microcontroller with TTL interface used logic as follows:
**Logic 1 == 5 volt.**
**Logic 0 == 0 volt.**

Computer with RS232 interface used logic as follows:
**Logic 1 == -3 volt until -25 volt.**
**Logic 0 == 0 until 25 volt.**

For connecting device TTL logic to RS232 logic can used **MAX232 IC**. MAX232 will translate your TTL logic to RS232 Logic.

Another options - cheaper and simple, used **TRANSISTOR** for convert TTL logic to RS232 logic vice versa, look at http://www.kmitl.ac.th/~kswichit/ap275/ap275.htm for details.

If need **send data without hardware handshaking**, only need **pin 2 (RX)**, **pin 3(TX)**, **pin 5(GND)**. If **need handshaking**, add **pin 7(RTS)** AND **pin 8(CTS)**.
Transmitte data as follows:

```
serialPort1.Open();
serialPort1.Write("your data in here");
```

Receive data as dollows:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(this.serialPort1_DataReceived);
    serialPort1.Open();
}

void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    string[] DataReceived; 

    while (serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0) 
    {
        DataReceived[i] = Convert.ToByte(serialPort1.ReadByte()); // data already in here
        i++;         

        if (i == int.MaxValue-1)
          i = 0;            
    }
    // Parsing your data in here
}
```

If just need **toggle output**, used pin 4 (DTR) **OR** pint 7(RTS).
`serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;`OR`serialPort1.RtsEnable = true;`