# How to send 5 volts power to RS232 cable through .net code?

Tags: .net, serial-port

I want to send 5 volts power to a RS232 cable using c# code.How to do this?

Comment: Do you want C# or VB? Please choose one or the other.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226580/c-sharp-sending-a-voltage-to-rs232 - check there for a few suggestions

Answer (score 2):

You can't... not really.  You don't get to choose the voltage of what comes out of an RS-232 port.  The RS-232 data pins can swing all the way up to +/- 15V, and only provide a very low amount of current.

Note that there are status lines, but they are also very low current.  Usually if you just open the port, the DTR status line goes high.

```
SomePort.Open()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx