# Sending fixed voltage to serial port

Tags: serial-port

I need to monitor if a door is opened. I have a sensor that continues to generate +5V DC as long as the door is shut but drops down to 0V once the door is opened.

I now need to connect the sensor's output wire to PC's serial port and write a program that continuously polls the port.

My thought is that various serial-io parameters such as baud rate, etc., does not matter in my case. For each byte that I read, I expect the value to be 255 (logical 1s) when the door is closed. Otherwise, I will assume that the door has been opened. Is there any flaw in this logic?

I went through [Sending a voltage to RS232](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226580/sending-a-voltage-to-rs232). It appears I just need to connect the wire to pin 2 (RX). However, for the serial port to receive a logical 1, it seems the voltage needs to be between -3V and -12V. As the voltage my sensor generates is positive, I am thinking I will connect the sensor wire to pin 5 (GND) instead and connect pin 2 to ground. In effect, I inverted the voltage. Will this work?

If this logic is flawed, I may have to buy a voltage inverter.

Finally, I was told that one should not connect anything to pin 5 on a motherboard's serial port. Apparently, it is hardwired to get grounded to the chassis. Is this true? Regards.

Comment: Your post is probably off-topic for this site, as it's not a programming question.  You also have made a slew of faulty assumptions, and misunderstood what little research you have done.  At the very least you will need a converter (logic to RS232) rather than a *"voltage inverter"*.

Comment: Thank you for your help. There are two parts to the question. During programming, do I need to worry about baud-rate, etc. or just continue to read byte after byte? Also, why do I need a converter when all I have is all-high or all-low?

Comment: RS-232 uses framing (i.e. start and stop bits) for each character.  A constant voltage is never detected as input frames/characters.  If you can generate the proper voltage levels and polarity, then maybe you could use idle (Mark state) versus break (Space state) on the RxD input.  RS-232 uses both positive and negative voltages for signal levels (typically +12v and -12v).  Zero volts is not used as a signal level.  That's basic RS-232 knowledge.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Turns out my problem had a simple solution. All I need to do is to connect my input to DSR pin. A simple ioctl call can get me the status of DSR pin.

Comment: *"Turns out my problem had a simple solution."* -- If you had paid attention to the link that you provided, you might have figured that out already.

Answer (score 2):

Like mentioned in the comments, constant high would not produce 255 bytes.
I would implement this by connecting the GND to GND and connecting the +5 Vdc to the CTS pin, which can be queried for his HIGH / LOW state.
But this is only a hack, you really should use some microcontroller.

Comment: *"connecting the +5 Vdc to the CTS pin ... But this is only a hack..."*  -- It's a hack that won't work.  A constant voltage (that's on the low side of the RS-232 range) conveys no information.

Comment: @sawdust CTS is not a data pin, it's a pin that can only be queried for his HIGH / LOW state (and used for flow control usually).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your help. You helped me look in the right direction. Turns out I can use either CTS or DSR pin. A simple ioctl() call can get me the desired status. Regards.

Comment: @IdanK -- I'm fully aware of the modem handshake and flow control pins.  But you only mention *one* (1) voltage state.  One more time: zero volts is not a valid RS-232 signal level.

Comment: I want to give this credits for being a "hack that actually works". Yes, zero volts is not a valid RS-232 voltage level, but you will find that a standard UART will translate +5V to CTS=On. While a 0V will be translated as CTS=Off. Here is the point: Your UART needs to give you either "on" or "off" as a state, there is no "undefined". So whatever falls below the +3V threshold for CTS=On is usually interpreted as CTS=Off and can be evaluated using a function like ioctl().